# Defiant Electronic Deadbolt does not retract fully

Tags: repair, doors, lock, deadbolt

Hi I installed a Defiant Electronic Deadbolt and for the past couple weeks it is not always opening properly. What happens is the bolt goes to retracts about 1/2 way and sort of sticks. Eventually the door opens and of course the lock itself errors and throws the red led.

Any Ideas? I know it was an inexpensive lock but still do not want to swap it out if there is a simple fix.

Comment: What model is it?

Comment: Does it always slide in and out correctly when the door is open?

Comment: I'd look for physical blockage, either inside the lick cavity or binding the bolt.

Comment: You need to determine if it is dragging on the strike plate or if it is rubbing in the deadbolt itself.  Would also try a drop of 3in1 oil on the deadbolt.  Other possibility is binding on the cam bar possibly from miss alignment.

Comment: I'd use [LockEase](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000CIJUGA/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480811840&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=lock+ease&dpPl=1&dpID=417G7eiU2wL&ref=plSrch) rather than 3in1 oil.  Over time 3in1 oil will both attract dirt and dry/harden.  Lock ease is dry graphit in a quick evaporating and penetrating liquid, it won't gum up in the future. @spicetraders

Comment: Thanks all, I took it apart sort of and adjusted both plates, added a little dry lube from the trailer and so far so good

Answer (score 1):

Answer from a comment made by the OP 6 years ago:

> I took it apart sort of and adjusted both plates, added a little dry lube from the trailer and so far so good